# PowerShell webdeploy

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell with web deployment based on this 
[article](http://blogs.iis.net/jamescoo/archive/2009/09/09/cool-msdeploy-powershell-scripts.aspx)

This is how my script looks like

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Deployment") 
function Sync-Provider($provider, $sourceLocation, $destLocation)  
{   
    $destBaseOptions   = new-object Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentBaseOptions   
    $syncOptions       = new-object Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncOptions   
    Try  
    {  
      $deploymentObject =                [Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager]::CreateObject($provider, $sourceLocation)     
      $deploymentObject.SyncTo($provider,$destLocation,$destBaseOptions,$syncOptions)  
    }  
    Catch  
    {  
      echo "EXCEPTION THROWN::[ $_ ] "  
      #throw $_  
    }  
}  
Sync-Provider   ("apphostConfig","D:\NerdDinner_2.0\NerdDinner","c:\inetpub\wwwroot")
```

Running this gives the following exception

```
EXCEPTION THROWN::[ Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "System.Object[]",
 for "CreateObject" to type "Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentWellKnownProvid
er": "Cannot convert value "apphostConfig,D:\NerdDinner_2.0\Ne
rdDinner,c:\inetpub\wwwroot" to type "Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentWellKn
ownProvider" due to invalid enumeration values. Specify one of the following en
umeration values and try again. The possible enumeration values are "Unknown, A
ppHostConfig, AppHostSchema, AppPoolConfig, ArchiveDir, Auto, Cert, ComObject32
, ComObject64, ContentPath, CreateApp, DirPath, DBFullSql, DBMySql, FilePath, G
acAssembly, IisApp, MachineConfig32, MachineConfig64, Manifest, MetaKey, Packag
e, RecycleApp, RegKey, RegValue, RootWebConfig32, RootWebConfig64, RunCommand, 
SetAcl, WebServer, WebServer60"." ]
```

Could you give me some hints on this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enclose the first parameter `[Microsoft.Web.Deployment]::DeploymentWellKnownProvider.AppHostConfig` with a pair of extra parenthesis: `([Microsoft.Web.Deployment]::DeploymentWellKnownProvider.AppHostConfig)`.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps the question was edited and my answer is not relevant anymore. There is "apphostConfig" now in the code. It's a good idea, too. Now you have to remove parens and commas and call your function like this: Sync-Provider `"apphostConfig" "D:\NerdDinner_2.0\NerdDinner" "c:\inetpub\wwwroot"`

Comment: However, I have another error.
EXCEPTION THROWN::[ Exception calling "CreateObject" with "2" argument(s): "Obj
ect of type 'appHostConfig' and path 'D:\NerdDinner_2.0\NerdDi
nner' cannot be created." ].
Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: I think that wrong `CreateObject(string, string)` is called because now you pass strings in. Restore the original version with the enum parameter and try again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the same problem, just opened the powershell console as Administrator and it worked.